# ServiceStack Redis Mq Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, redis, servicestack, message-queue

The way Service Stack lets me call existing Web Service endpoints from a message broker is fantastic.  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis

But question is how do I authenticate those endpoints?  Service Stack provides very convenient attribute based system for locking down web service calls.  e.g.

```
[Authenticate]
//All HTTP (GET, POST...) methods need "CanAccess"
[RequiredRole("Admin")]
[RequiredPermission("CanAccess")]
[RequiredPermission(ApplyTo.Put | ApplyTo.Post, "CanAdd")]
[RequiredPermission(ApplyTo.Delete, "AdminRights", "CanDelete")]
public class Secured
{
   public bool Test { get; set; }
}
```

But when I access this Dto from the message broker all of the authentication attributes are ignored.  Can someone point be to documentation about doing authentication in servicestack over a message broker?

Answer (score 1):

The Messaging API are [treated as Internal Requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters#message-queue-endpoints) and follow a [different Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations#mq-non-http-custom-hooks) to HTTP Requests.

Comment: Wow!  An answer from the man himself.  Thank you.  I'm still having a bit of trouble getting started with GlobalMessageRequest/ResponseFilters.  I've looked through the docs/unit tests but can't seem to find much in the way of examples.  Anymore advice?  Thanks!

Comment: @RyanHartman It works in the same way as GlobalRequestFilters, e.g. here's an example of the ValidationFeature registering [Global HTTP and MQ Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Validation/ValidationFeature.cs#L28-L29)